# How to transform a text file with tab separated fields to a pipe separated fields in pentaho?

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration, data-integration

I have a situation where I want to transform a text file which has tab spaced fields like in the 'space-separated.png' below.

I want to transform this file by replacing tabs with pipes(|) like the 'pipe-separated.png' file below.

How can I do this in pentaho?

[image]

space-separated.png

[image]

pipe-separated.png

Answer (score 1):

It can be achieved by a transformation with two steps.

1. Text file input (specify TAB as the separator in the content tab)
2. Text file output (specify | as the separator in the content tab)

Remember to click on 'Get Fields' option in both the steps. Not clicking on 'Get Fields' is what took me time.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want for any reason load as TEXT FILE OUTPUT step, you also can read the file text, without delimeter, so entire data will be in a row, use REPLACE IN STRING step, REGEX YES and search \t, replace for |. thats all.

all data in a field:

[data view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bUzCK.png)

Replace in string step:

[Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9O3rS.png)

Preview result:

[result with pipe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MNCHj.png)